# Dataflow operation on a variable is making it a don't care term (Verilog)

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, vivado, adder

I want to implement a 4-bit parallel adder and subtractor using the same circuit while using a control input variable to switch between addition and subtraction. When my `ctrl` input variable is 0, I want the operation to be addition and subtraction when it is 1.  When it is subtraction, I want to ignore the last carry out.

Here is my code,

```
module p4bitadd_sub( output [4:0]sum,input ctrl,[3:0]a,b);

wire c1,c2,c3;

fadder ad0(a[0],ctrl^b[0],ctrl, sum[0], c1);
fadder ad1(a[1],ctrl^b[1],c1, sum[1], c2);
fadder ad2(a[2],ctrl^b[2],c2, sum[2], c3);
fadder ad3(a[3],ctrl^b[3],c3, sum[3], sum[4]);
assign sum[4] = (~ctrl)&sum[4];

endmodule

module fadder(input a,b,cin,output s,cout);

assign s=a^b^cin;
assign cout = (a&b)|(b&cin)|(cin&a);

endmodule
```

My testbench,

```
module p4bitadd_sun_tb();

reg [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] b;
reg ctrl;
wire [4:0] s;

p4bitadd_sub dut(.sum(s),.a(a),.b(b),.ctrl(ctrl));
initial begin

ctrl=0;a=4'b1000;b=4'b0100;
#5
$display("Addition:");
$display("   %b%b%b%b",a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
$display("  +%b%b%b%b",b[3],b[2],b[1],b[0]);
$display("  -----");
$display("  %b%b%b%b%b",s[4],s[3],s[2],s[1],s[0]);
ctrl=0;a=4'b0101;b=4'b0011;
#5
$display("");
$display("   %b%b%b%b",a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
$display("  +%b%b%b%b",b[3],b[2],b[1],b[0]);
$display("  -----");
$display("  %b%b%b%b%b",s[4],s[3],s[2],s[1],s[0]);
ctrl=1;a=4'b1000;b=4'b0100;
#5
$display("Subtraction:");
$display("   %b%b%b%b",a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
$display("  -%b%b%b%b",b[3],b[2],b[1],b[0]);
$display("  -----");
$display("  %b%b%b%b%b",s[4],s[3],s[2],s[1],s[0]);
ctrl=1;a=4'b0101;b=4'b0011;
#5
$display("");
$display("   %b%b%b%b",a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
$display("  -%b%b%b%b",b[3],b[2],b[1],b[0]);
$display("  -----");
$display("  %b%b%b%b%b",s[4],s[3],s[2],s[1],s[0]);

$finish;
end
endmodule
```

My console output:

[image: addition output]

[image: subtraction output]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `p4bitadd_sub` module.  Your code has multiple drivers for the `sum[4]` bit.

One driver is the output of the `ad3` instance:

```
fadder ad3(a[3],ctrl^b[3],c3, sum[3], sum[4]);
```

The other driver is the continuous assignment:

```
assign sum[4] = (~ctrl)&sum[4];
```

When you have multiple drivers of a signal, you can have contention, and contention results in an `x` value in Verilog.  `x` is the unknown value, or "don't care" value.

You need to change the code in the `p4bitadd_sub` module so that `sum[4]` is not driven this way.  One way is to add a new wire (`c4`):

```
module p4bitadd_sub( output [4:0]sum,input ctrl,[3:0]a,b);

wire c1,c2,c3,c4;

fadder ad0(a[0],ctrl^b[0],ctrl, sum[0], c1);
fadder ad1(a[1],ctrl^b[1],c1, sum[1], c2);
fadder ad2(a[2],ctrl^b[2],c2, sum[2], c3);
fadder ad3(a[3],ctrl^b[3],c3, sum[3], c4);
assign sum[4] = (~ctrl)&c4;

endmodule
```

Output:

```
Addition:
   1000
  +0100
  -----
  01100

   0101
  +0011
  -----
  01000

Subtraction:
   1000
  -0100
  -----
  00100

   0101
  -0011
  -----
  00010
```

If you aren't already doing so, you should also dump waveforms for your simulation.  Looking at waves can make it much easier to see values of internal signals than just `$display` statements alone.  This is how I quickly narrowed down the problem with your code.